# angular reactive form - bind another property other than [value]

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular reactive form with a select box as follows:

```
<select formControlName="incomeSourceId">
    <option value="" disabled >Select a source</option>
    <option *ngFor="let source of primarySourceIncome"  [value]="source.value">{{source.viewValue}}</option>
</select>
```

I would like to show/hide sections depending on the dropdown selection. So far I have:

```
<div class="row" [hidden]="applicationForm.get('incomeSourceId').value !== '1'"></div>
<div class="row" [hidden]="applicationForm.get('incomeSourceId').value !== '2'"></div>
```

component:

```
this.applicationForm = this.fb.group({     
  incomeSourceId: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)]]   

})
```

This works however, my logic is based on the value, which is an ID returned from the server. I would prefer to build this logic to check against `{{source.viewValue}}`, that will not change. How can I bind another property to the form `<option>`? NgModel does not work within a form group.

Comment: so you mean to say `[value]`doesn't work in this case

Comment: Correct. [value]="source.value" is set to an id which is populated from the server, and sent to the server. It is subject to change whereas {{source.viewValue}} will stay the same and is a string such as "Employed"

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your need? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select formControlName="incomeSourceId">
    <option value="" disabled >Select a source</option>
    <option *ngFor="let source of primarySourceIncome"  [ngValue]="source.value">{{source.viewValue}}</option> // change to [ngValue]
</select>
```

> If the value is not a string [ngValue]="..." must be used.
>   [value]="..." only supports strings.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the index of the current primarySourceIncome as the value:

```
<option *ngFor="let source of primarySourceIncome; index as i" [value]="i">{{source.viewValue}}</option>
```

If that select input's value is important for saving, then before you save you'll want to look for that index in the primarySourceIncome and set the value to what it should really be.

Answer (score 0):

Might seem like a workaround, but I think it's still clean.

Have a `(change)` event in your select, where we just use `find()` to find the object in your array with that `value`. This way we get the corresponding `viewValue` to that `value`. In this case, when names are long, I like to store them in variables, for easier use, so for your formcontrol, I'd do this after building form

```
this.idCtrl = this.applicationForm.get('incomeSourceId');
```

Then the `change` event triggered by the `select`, we'll just assign the `viewValue` from the chosen object to a variable `viewVal`

```
findViewValue() {
  this.viewVal = this.primarySourceIncome.find(x => 
     x.value == this.idCtrl.value).viewValue
}
```

Since you mentioned that the `viewValue` doesn't change, we have here just used the string literals in template. Also I have used `[ngSwitch]` here, looks cleaner I think :) So for example, the template could look like this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="viewVal">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'Employee'">Employee</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'Manager'">Manager</div>
</div>
```

Also this takes away of calling "unnecessary" `get` requests in template.